# Is it possible to create a WorkFlow in OSworkflow dynamically?

Tags: java, xml, osworkflow

Is it possible to create workflows dynamically? I need to generate a WF dynamically. Is it possible for me to generate the example.layout.xml dynamically without using the designer.I need this in java.Is there any runtime designing method so that i can design the workflow dynamically and generate the corrosponding layout.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help someone else even when the post is kind of old ... Searching for a similar solution, I found some posts right here on stackoverflow, the conclusion can be that [jBPM](http://www.jboss.org/jbpm) can provide a way to do this.

Hope this helps.